# Iptables: How do I block all outgoing traffic on a network interface except for a single port

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

I am very new to using Iptables, and I am attempting to only allow the outgoing tcp traffic from port 51355 on eth0

Here is an attempt based on what I have found online so far:

iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 ! -p tcp --dport 51355-j DROP

When this is run I get an invalid argument error.  Any help would be much appreciated/

Answer (score 1):

you must specify which module you want to use  before use `!` .

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp ! --dport 51355 -j DROP
```

with `iptables-save -c`  you can see how many times each rule is used

Now if you want to some more complex , somestime  is better to create a `chain`

A more complex example , with a creation of a `chain` :

```
iptables -N FILTERBOT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -j FILTERBOT
iptables -A FILTERBOT -p udp -j RETURN
iptables -A FILTERBOT -p tcp -m tcp ! --dport 51355 -j DROP
iptables -A FILTERBOT -m limit --limit 1/s -j LOG --log-prefix "CHAIN-FILTERBOT:"
iptables -A FILTERBOT -j DROP
```

PS: more informations for each module in   `man iptables-extensions`

Comment: Thank you, this is what I am looking for and the extra info is much appreciated for learning more about iptables!

Answer (score 1):

I recomend to you first give permision to the trafic of dport 51355 and then drop everything else on the interface

like

```
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp -o eth0 --sport 51355 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -j DROP
```

Comment: Thanks so much I will give this a try